# Automatically scroll down

Tags: html, css, frontend, salesforce

I have a lightning web component that will auto create a scroll bar when there is too much content to fit within the max height of the container/div.
When more content is added, the component stays in the same place, so the user has to use the scroll bar to see the new content.
I would rather it automatically scroll down when new content is added.
I have a js function that is adding the new content, so I know when it will need to scroll, just not how to do it.

Is there a way I can create a method that automatically scrolls to the bottom of the div?
Is there a way to make it look smooth?

For context, this is the css style for the div with the scroll bar:

```css
.main-content{
  display        : flex;
  flex-direction : column;
  overflow-y     : auto;
  padding        : 10px;
  min-height     : 0px;
  max-height     : 500px;
  }
```

Comment: you need js code for this

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using `scrollIntoView()` method in javascript. ([more info here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView))

I would suggest something like this:

```
element.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth", block: "end", inline: "nearest", alignToTop: false});
```

(element refers to the element you want to target)